# Image border on DIV

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use an image of width 480px and height 360px and apply it to a `div` as a border? I know its possible to implement the below css code as a border, but I can not seem to work out how to use an image instead.

```
border:1px solid blue;
```

Comment: Can you please make clear your question or can you upload any image or diagram to show what you want to do?

Comment: Hi Sikander, I am working on this website http://www.theartisanscorner.com.au/index.php and i would like to use an image border on the DIV #container which is the big box all the contents in. Many thanks, Deryn.

Comment: Hi Tarun, the image ill like to use is the "colorbox" one i placed on http://www.theartisanscorner.com.au/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=11. I would like to use the edges of that :)

Answer (score 4):

CSS3 spec has the `border-image` property. Check out this article: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/ for information on how to use it.

To summarize:

You apply the border-image like so:

```
border-image: url(border-image.png) 25% repeat;
```

by providing a URL to your image, where to slice your image and the behavior of applying the image to the element's border.

Comment: +1  Note that it includes "Predictably, IE doesn't understand anything of border-image." but then again good old css3 pie comes to the rescue... http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-image for IE versions 6+

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do this using a trick. Check out my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/WbjWd/1/) using `Google` as border-image

Basically, the idea is having two divs.

```
<div id="borderDiv"><!-- This will serve as the border -->
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#borderDiv {
    padding: 2px; /* This is the width of the border :P */
    background: url("borderimage.png");
}
#inner {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the answer with CSS3 and the one with the nested divs are good answers, but it depends on what you value most. If the border image is crucial to your design, a good rule of thumb is to use the most widely supported solution. In this case that would be the nested divs. However, if semantic markup and ease are more important to you, use CSS3 to design the border image. Just realize that there will be less browser support, and thus a smaller audience that can appreciate the effect.

Most importantly, know your primary audience and the browsers they use. Design for them.